# Maven Deployment to Nexus

Tags: maven, nexus

I wish to upload a binary from one of the child Maven modules to Nexus. This child module tar.gz's jars from other child modules using maven assembly plugin.

question 1#: So should I add the distributionmanagement section to just that particular child module? Or should I add distributionmanagement to parent modules and all other child modules?

question#2: Is it enough to make changes to distributionmanagement and settings.xml? Or should I include "maven deploy plugin" too somewhere?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You're not specifying where you'll be deploying the artifacts from, so I'm assuming you have some sort of CI server like Jenkins or TeamCity already installed.

> question 1#: So should I add the distributionmanagement section to
>   just that particular child module? Or should I add
>   distributionmanagement to parent modules and all other child modules?

If you'd like to deploy just that module's artifact, then I would recommend you have a separate job for this in your CI server. Alternatively, when deploying from a command-line, you would need to `cd` in the directory of the module and only execute `mvn deploy` from there. And -- yes -- you will need to have the `<distributionManagement/>` section for sure.

> question#2: Is it enough to make changes to distributionmanagement and
>   settings.xml? Or should I include "maven deploy plugin" too somewhere?

You will need both a `<distributionManagement/>` section in your pom and a properly defined `<server/>` section in your `pom.xml`. You shouldn't need to explicitly define settings for the `maven-deploy-plugin`, unless you need some special options.

Comment: Thx Carlspring...I fixed it...I am able to push to releases repository now...But I am unable to push to Snapshot repository...Getting error 401 : unauthorized...Maybe you think it has to do with my access issues to snapshot repository? Thanks

Comment: Perhaps your user doesn't have the `Deployment` role assigned in Nexus.

Answer (score 0):

1. You only need distributiionManagement in some parent pom you are inheriting from. Typically this is only set up in an organization wide top level pom. You do NOT need to have it in every project since it is inherited.
2. Settings has to be configured correctly.
3. All you need to do is call mvn deploy for the module you want to deploy.

Check out the first videos of the [Nexus training video series](http://www.sonatype.com/training/free-nexus-training).. it shows it all.

Comment: Thx Manfred...I fixed it...I am able to push to releases repository now...But I am unable to push to Snapshot repository...Getting error 401 : unauthorized...Maybe you think it has to do with my access issues to snapshot repository? Thanks

Comment: Make sure your url in distribution management points to a snapshot repo url in the snapshotRepository section and that your user has access to that repo.